# clearInterval.bind() does not work as a parameter passed into addEventListener

Tags: javascript

I was wondering why `clearInterval.bind` doesn't work as a parameter passed into `addEventListener` function. Simple example to emulate situation.

*html*

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="end">End</button>
<div id="app"></div>
```

*js*

```
var timer;
var i = 0;
document.getElementById('start')
    .addEventListener('click',function(){
       timer = setInterval(function(){
         document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = i
         i ++
    }, 1000)
},false)


document.getElementById('end')
    .addEventListener('click',clearInterval.bind(window,timer),false);
```

Everything works as expected when i surround `clearInterval` into anonymous function like below.

```
document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('click',function(){
    clearInterval.bind(window,timer)();
    // or just simple clearInterval(timer)
},false);
```

Why it doesn't want work? Did i miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of `timer` is passed to `bind`. At the time that code runs, the value is `undefined` (because you haven't clicked on *start* yet). So you bind `undefined` in the new function.

Variables are not passed by reference in JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin, You are so quick  :))